# ListView with 2 color does not interleaving

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying do a ListView with 2 color, interleaving colors white and grey. In my adapter on the getView method I do the following code:

```
if(position % 2 == 0){
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}else{
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_grey_listas);
}
 return v;
```

But in my screen, sometimes a group of lines is with the same color. For example, 3 line with grey background color or when I navigate in the list view the line change for the wrong color

Comment: Post the whole adapter code, it possible you are using holder pattern and not dealing with it right.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

These are the following steps to do show.

Step1.1) Use two selector for odd and even postion list item

artists_list_backgroundcolor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/grey" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
</selector>
```

Step 1.2)
artists_list_background_alternate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/sign_out_color" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/login_hover" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/login_hover" />
</selector>
```

Step2)
colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="survey_toplist_item">#EFEDEC</color>
    <color name="survey_alternate_color">#EBE7E6</color>
    <color name="grey">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="itemselected">#EDEDED</color>
    <color name="login_hover">#E5F5FA</color>
    <color name="sign_out_color">#e84040</color>

</resources>



@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        }

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_background_alternate);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading)).setText(data.get(position));

        return view;
    }
}
```

You can get full description in the below link

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-alternate-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this getView() method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
            view.setTag(hoder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_background_alternate);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading)).setText(data.get(position));

        return view;
    }

 class ViewHolder {
        //Declare here your listview variables      }
```